# Flex How can I change item in dataProvider when Items is selected or deselected in the mx:List

Tags: list, apache-flex

Flex How can I change item in dataProvider when Items(multiple selection) is selected or deselected in the mx:List

I just want my data reflect what items I selected in the list dynamically. Base on that do some sorting with the list, for example make selected items first in the list when they are selected, and go back to original place when items are deselected....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IViewCursor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/IViewCursor.html) to `get/add/remove` items of the list.

Below is a code example of how to create the cursor, based on that you will just need to apply the logic you need.

```
var col:ICollectionView =  ICollectionView(list.dataProvider);
var myCursor:IViewCursor = col.createCursor(); 
//do the logic using the myCursor functions
...
//refresh the collection to the changes reflect in the list
col.refresh();
```

[Here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=about_dataproviders_4.html) you can check some more info about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to your list so that whenever a selection/deselection occurs it triggers.

```
<s:List id="myList"
    labelField="firstName" 
    change="selectionChangedHandler(event)"
    dataProvider="{peopleArray}">
</s:List>

....
protected function selectionChangedHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
{
    var currentIndx:int = event.currentTarget.selectedIndex;
    var currentDataItem:Object = event.currentTarget.selectedItem;
    peopleArray.removeItemAt(currentIndx);
    peopleArray.addItemAt(currentDataItem,0);
    peopleArray.refresh();
}
```

I haven't run it but you may need to set selection on refreshed list too.